# If statement using Bitwise AND Operators to force evaluations

Tags: javascript, if-statement, bitwise-operators

I have several independent functions which return either true or false depending other conditions. When they all return true I want an action to occur, however I want all of the functions to run regardless of how many return false. If I just wanted to check all of the functions were returning true I would use:

```
if (func1() && func2() && func3() ){
    //Some code
}
```

The problem with this is that if one of the functions returns false all of the functions to the right will not execute. One method I haven't tried before is using Bitwise AND Operators (&) in the if expression, which would look like:

```
if (func1() & func2() & func3() ){
    //Some code
}
```

I have briefly tested this method and it seems to be producing the desired outcome however I could not find this method used elsewhere and I am wondering if there is any reason that this could produce a unexpected outcome?

Also is there is a good reason not to compare the results of the functions using this method?

Comment: My best guess is that the functions "must" be evaluated in order to do the bitwise comparison otherwise its more efficient to stop when it finds something falsey. I don't really see an issue with it as long as your return types are in check.

Comment: Personally I think it's a questionable design decision to rely on side-effects like that. It makes the code fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're just returning boolean true/false operations, then it'll work as expected:

```
if (true & false & true)
```

would simply be "false".

But if they're turning (say) integers, then you're going to get unexpected results:

```
if (10 & 100 & 32)
```

would be

```
if (b1010 & b1100100 & b100000)
```

and evaluate to false.

Comment: Wouldn't proper use of `!!` fix the integer case?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the functions return only `true` or `false`, there is no problem using the `&` operator. For that specific case (booleans as operands and the whole result evaluated as a boolean) it works exactly as the `&&` operator except not doing short-circuit evaluation.

(It would also work if the functions returned the numeric values `1` and `0`. That is what the `true` and `false` values are converted to before the operation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to steer clear of bitwise operators you could also achieve it like

```
const results = [func1(), func2(), func3(), ...funcN())

if (results.every(Boolean)) {
  /* Do something */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following.

```
(func1() || func2() || func3()) && otherAction()
```

Its called short circuiting.

Answer (score -2):

> The problem with this is that if one of the functions returns false all of the functions to the right will not execute

This is not a problem. The `if` conditional checks true/false and if one of the values passed in when using `&&` is a false value then the conditional short circuits and doesn't bother executing the rest of the statement.

That is the whole purpose of `&&`

Comment: I know that that is what && is meant to do. However in my script I do not want this behavior. Which is what I meant by a problem.

Comment: @Oracle well I was answering the part where you asked
>Also is there is a good reason not to compare the results of the functions using this method?